# Mark a new location on mapbox after getting new coordinates

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am using Mapbox where user can select any location. I am getting the new location but I am unable to add a marker on a new location. Below is my code.

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [data.Latitude, data.Longitude],
    zoom: 12
});

map.on('click', function (e) {

    var latitude = e.lngLat.lat;
    var longitude = e.lngLat.lng;

    console.log(latitude + " - " + longitude)
    var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat([latitude, longitude])
        .addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include which version of `mapbox-gl-js` you are currently using? This will help members of the community provide a better informed response.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are passing the coordinates in the reverse order than expected by the function:

```js
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat([latitude, longitude])
        .addTo(map);
```

Can you try this:

```js
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat([longitude, latitude])
        .addTo(map);
```

Please let me know if that helps!